# What is wrong with this LTspiceIV model of a Deliyannis bandpass filter

Tags: ltspice, active-filter

I'm trying to analyze a Deliyannis bandpass filter at fc=7.15Mhz. I have constructed the following in LTspiceIV:
[image]

which results in the following net list:

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\LTC\LTspiceIV\Draft1.asc
XU1 0 N005 N002 N003 N006 LT1818
V1 N003 N006 5
C1 N002 N001 2.7p
C2 N005 N001 2.7p
R1 N004 N001 8450
R2 N001 0 432
R3 N002 N005 165k
V2 N004 0 AC 1
R4 N002 0 50
.ac lin 1000 6MEG 8MEG
.lib LTC2.LIB
.backanno
.end
```

However the results are not, it seems, consistent with a bandpass filter:
[image]

It should be noted that I am new to spice and rf circuits, so there could be several errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Your supply isn't ground-referenced. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Good point by bhillam. Put two 2.5V supplies in series and ground reference the tie point between them, and use them as a split supply for the amplifier. Floating amplifier supplies will indeed give very strange results.

Comment: Also try measuring from 1 to 20MHz in case you've simply missed the frequency peak thanks to parasitic components (like Cin of the opamp, probably > 2,7pf...)

Comment: Thank you. Both issues were affecting the results. Referencing the supply achieved the bandpass behavior. Increasing the analysis bandwidth allowed me to see the peak was <1Mhz.